# How to replace a group of documents without "downtime" in Solr?

Tags: solr

i have a solr standalone server (not solr cloud), holding documents from a few different sources.

Routinely i need to update the documents for a source, typically i do this by deleting all documents from that source/group, and indexing the new documents for that source, but this creates a time gap where i have no documents for that source, and that's not ideal.
Some of these documents will probably remain from one update to the other, some change and could be updated, but some may disappear, and need to get deleted.

What's the best way to do this?

Is there a way to delete all documents from a source, but not committing, and in the same transaction index that source again and only then commit? (that would not create a time gap of no information for that source)

Is using core swapping a solution? (or am i over complicating?)

Comment: Does your client know which documents have to be added or updated, and which documents have to be deleted? If yes, you can simply add the documents to add or update (adding a document with an existing unique ID will overwrite the existing document), and delete the documents that need to be deleted. I think this would be the cleanest way of doing what you need.

Comment: Yes, but the client doesn't know which ones will have to be deleted

Comment: Then how about having a timestamp in each document, representing the last time it was added (i.e. added for the first time, or modified). You could do all the updates for a source, commit this, then delete anything from that source that is too old, then commit the delete. It would eliminate the time gap you're concerned about; if a time gap where some extra documents are indexed is ok, this would be a working solution.

Comment: Yeah, that would be ok, in fact i was already changing it to be something very similar to what you suggested, but with a revision instead of a timestamp, (not sure i trust clocks)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need a live index which will keep serving queries while you update the index without having any downtime. In a way you are partially re-indexing your data.

You can look into maintaining two indices, and interacting with them using ALIASES. 
Check this link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multiple-indices.html 
Although its on Elasticsearch website, you can easily use the concepts in solr.

Here is another link on how to create/use ALIASES 
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/10/collection-aliasing-near-real-time-search-for-really-big-data/

> Collection aliases are also useful for re-indexing – especially when
>   dealing with static indices. You can re-index in a new collection
>   while serving from the existing collection. Once the re-index is
>   complete, you simply swap in the new collection and then remove the
>   first collection using your read side aliases.